# Persist Twitter OAuth session

Tags: oauth, twitter

I have a Twitter web app that allows users to submit tweets from my site. However they have to re-login every time they submit a new tweet. Is there a way to save the OAuth session and don't prompt the login screen until users clear their browser cache?

Answer (score 4):

When you get the callback from Twitter after the user has validated you, you'll receive an auth_token in the headers of the request;  you're meant to cache that token, and supply it every time the user makes a request.

It sounds like you're not caching that token and supplying it when the user makes a request.

Comment: so many tokens, so confusing :) so the one I need to cache is auth_token of that user?

Answer (score 4):

You need to store the `oauth_token`, you can use the same for all requests.

On the [FAQ of Twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq)

> How long does an access token last?
>
> We do not currently expire access
> tokens. Your access token will be
> invalid if a user explicitly rejects
> your application from their settings
> or if a Twitter admin suspends your
> application. If your application is
> suspended there will be a note on your
> application page saying that it has
> been suspended.

Answer (score 1):

you need a db tables called user and user_tokens. Inside the user you have: id, user_oauth_secret, user_oauth_token. Inside the the user_token you need this columns: id, user_id, token, created, expires. make sure this token is unique (and long) with some random hash. now you can save this token to the user's cookie and find the right oauth data later.

Comment: whats the purpose of the user_tokens table? can't I store everything in the user table? thx

Comment: because its a 1:n relationship. user can login form different computers and still be logged in on the first one. unless time() > expires.

Comment: i see. so which is stored user tokens is sent to twitter? is it user_oauth_secret? which one is for the cookie?

Comment: ok so is this right? my app checks user browse for cookie, if it matches user_token.token and it'not not expired, sent the corresponding user.user_oauth_secret

Comment: i think you need user_oauth_secret and user_oauth_token to successfully auth to twitter. you need to save them after the users logs in (they are send as get vars from twitter). you are right about the cookie.

Comment: what if a user has two twitter accounts? (and use the same browser) how would my site tell which twitter account is he currently signed in?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store two tokens.

When you make the OAuth request the first time, it will show the Twitter auth screen. After auth, your OAuth callback page will get two query string parameters, "oauth_token" and "oauth_token_secret" for the user. You need to store these (probably in a database) somewhere.

Then, when you request OAuth permission again from Twitter, send the two tokens, and the user will automatically be authorized.

You shouldn't have to code this yourself. There are plenty of OAuth libraries out there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain a long session with the user and save the access tokens. Cookies are commonly used to recognize users.